# C# remove empty url parameters regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove empty url type parameters from a string using C#. My code sample is here.

```
    public static string test ()
    {
        string parameters = "one=aa&two=&three=aaa&four=";
        string pattern = "&[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*=&";
        string replacement = "";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = rgx.Replace(parameters, replacement);

        return parameters;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test());
    }
```

I tried the code in [rextester](http://rextester.com/)

output: `one=aa&two=&three=aaa&four=`

expected output: `one=aa&three=aaa`

Comment: Try `(?:^|&)[a-zA-Z]+=(?=&|$)` instead.

Comment: Why use Regex?  You could just use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?:^|&)[a-zA-Z]+=(?=&|$)
```

This matches start of string or an ampersand (`(?:^|&)`) followed by at least one (english) letter (`[a-zA-Z]+`), an equal sign (`=`) and then nothing, made sure by the positive look-ahead (`(?=&|$)`) which matches end of string or a new parameter (started by `&`).

Code:

```
public static string test ()
{
    string parameters = "one=aa&two=&three=aaa&four=";
    string pattern = "(?:^|&)[a-zA-Z]+=(?=&|$)";
    string replacement = "";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = rgx.Replace(parameters, replacement);

    return result;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test());
}
```

Note that this also returns the correct variable (as pointed out by Joel Anderson)

[See it live here at ideone](https://ideone.com/aVkK7o).

Comment: thank you that worked, will accept your answer when it will be available

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely do not need to roll your own Regex for this, try using [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string RemoveEmptyUrlParameters(string input)
{
    var results = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(input);

    Dictionary<string, string> nonEmpty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var k in results.AllKeys)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(results[k]))
        {
            nonEmpty.Add(k, results[k]);
        }
    }

    return string.Join("&", nonEmpty.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"));
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cm9wr2)

Answer (score 0):

The results of the Regex replace is not returned by the function.  The function returns the variable "parameters", which is never updated or changed.

```
string parameters = "one=aa&two=&three=aaa&four=";
...
string result = rgx.Replace(parameters, replacement);
return parameters;
....
```

Perhaps you meant

```
return results;
```